# one div has to append to main_div when i click another div

Tags: jquery

I am new to jquery. I have a basic need for it in my application.

On the left side, I have small `div`s (`div1`, `div2`...), and, in the center of the page, I have one main `div`.

When I click on `div1`, another `sub_div` has to be appended to the main `div`.

Here is my code, so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#div1").click(function(){
        $("#sub_div").show().//here sub div has to append main_div
    });
});
```

The requirement is that when I click on `div1`, `sub_div` has to be appended to `main_div`.

Comment: Is `$('#main_div').append('#sub_div')` what your looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [appendTo()](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/):

```
$("#div1").click(function(){

    $("#sub_div").show().appendTo('#main_div');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also make something like this if you just want to add new content to the existing main div:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#div1").click(function(){
               var mainContent = $("#main_div").html(); //getting the existent content
               var newContent = "<your-new-content>"; //the content you want to add

               $("#main_div").html(mainContent + newContent); // setting it 

               // if you want the new content to be on top just switch them
               //  $("#main_div").html(newContent + mainContent);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) or [`.prepend()`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) however you want
take a look for it.

it solve your problem